# Acos & Asin substitute in Access

Tags: algorithm, ms-access

How can I calculate track & distance & wind vectors  in Access. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately you have Arctan in Access, so you can use the fact that if
`x = sin(y)` then `tan(y) = x/sqrt(1-x^2)`.  In access:

```
 Const PI As Double = 3.14159265359
 aSin = Atn(val / Sqr(1 - val * val))
 aCos = PI / 2 - aSin
```

Hope this helps.